# tikz circle with number change vertical space between lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing, baseline

Arg, i try to replicate the diverse answers using `tikz` i read into this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199026/how-can-i-draw-circled-integers-with-the-same-size-by-tikz) and in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers), without success, my circle explode the space between lines.

Don't understand why the result is different ...

[image]

There the cthullu MWE :

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[anchor=text, shape=circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,text=white,minimum size=2em] (char) {#1\strut};}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh \circled{1} wgah'nagl fhtagn. Nog Chaugnar Faugn ooboshu 'fhalma ron, uln syha'h zhro lloig 'fhalma ph'hlirgh ep sgn'wahl ph'kn'a, hai kadishtu shagg kn'a stell'bsna naflmnahn' gotha 'fhalma uaaah. Gof'nnog \circled{3} shagg hrii 'ai uaaah ngthrod geboth h'ep ooboshu syha'h, gof'nn epyar sgn'wahl nilgh'ri orr'e Yoggothoth ep wgah'n. Gof'nnagl athg Azathothagl k'yarnak \circled{2} gof'nn Dagon, uln 'fhalma throd phlegeth wgah'nog 'fhalma, nnnHastur uh'e chtenff r'luh. Stell'bsna hlirgh Shub-Niggurath orr'e lw'nafh R'lyeh, lw'nafh ep grah'n li'hee, r'luh gof'nn nw 'fhalma. H'gof'nn ng'fhalma ngehye h'shtunggli Dagon orr'e k'yarnak geb athg ee R'lyeh orr'e, 'aior nnnDagon Shub-Niggurath y-Tsathoggua hrii nog Chaugnar Faugn Nyarlathotepnyth lw'nafh nashagg stell'bsna, fm'latgh zhro nallll ee Nyarlathotep n'ghft ehye nglui naron sgn'wahl. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the `\tikz` in the definition of `\circled` is responsible for the added line spacing.  One can treat the height of an object as zero with the `\smash{}` macro.  So here, I `\smash{\tikz[...]{...}}`.

Of course, this now makes overlap a possibility.  In an effort to combat this, I reduced the minimum size of the circle to 1.4em.

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\smash{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[anchor=text, shape=circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,text=white,minimum size=1.4em] (char) {#1\strut};}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sloppy
    Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh \circled{1} wgah'nagl fhtagn. Nog Chaugnar Faugn ooboshu 'fhalma ron, uln syha'h zhro lloig 'fhalma ph'hlirgh ep sgn'wahl ph'kn'a, hai kadishtu shagg kn'a stell'bsna naflmnahn' gotha 'fhalma uaaah. Gof'nnog \circled{3} shagg hrii 'ai uaaah ngthrod geboth h'ep ooboshu syha'h, gof'nn epyar sgn'wahl nilgh'ri orr'e Yoggothoth ep wgah'n. Gof'nnagl athg Azathothagl k'yarnak \circled{2} gof'nn Dagon, uln 'fhalma throd phlegeth wgah'nog 'fhalma, nnnHastur uh'e chtenff r'luh. Stell'bsna hlirgh Shub-Niggurath orr'e lw'nafh R'lyeh, lw'nafh ep grah'n li'hee, r'luh gof'nn nw 'fhalma. H'gof'nn ng'fhalma ngehye h'shtunggli Dagon orr'e k'yarnak geb athg ee R'lyeh orr'e, 'aior nnnDagon Shub-Niggurath y-Tsathoggua hrii nog Chaugnar Faugn Nyarlathotepnyth lw'nafh nashagg stell'bsna, fm'latgh zhro nallll ee Nyarlathotep n'ghft ehye nglui naron sgn'wahl. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to also reduce the size of the circle ?

Comment: @reyman64 Please see revision.